# stuck on a PHP program. Need some idea

Tags: php

Want to make a php program, where there will be a drop down which will contain some name of brands .. after selecting the " first drop down/ brands" products of the selected brand will show on another drop down.. need help . anyone ?

Comment: *This question does not show any research effort...* to quote the downvote button.

Comment: This is not a coding service. Please post your attempted code and research. Also post the error/non-required behavior that you are getting.

Comment: the values that should come in new select box is static or you should fetch from database??

Comment: You will have to use ajax.. can u paste your attempted code?

Comment: @Niranjan37 .. it will fetch from database

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a forum, you should only ask concrete questions. What you request is too broad. You should first research what you intend to do, and when you have a question first search if it has answered before (you will probably find your answer without the need to ask a new question). Good luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use javascript function onchange select element and fetch records according to selected first select element value.

```
<form name="product" method="post" >
<select id="category" name="category" onChange="relodme()">
    <option value=''></option>
    <?php
    $qry = "select * from category order by name";
    $res = mysql_query($qry) or die ("MYSQL ERROR:".mysql_error());
    while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        ?> 
            <option value="<?=$arr['category_id']?>" <? if($_POST['category'] == $arr['category_id']) { ?> selected="selected" <? } ?> ><?=$arr['name']?></option>
        <?
    }

    ?>
</select>

<select id="Type" name="Type"  >
    <option value=''></option>
    <?php
    $qry = "select * from subcategory where category_id = '".$_POST['category']."' order by name";
    $res = mysql_query($qry) or die ("MYSQL ERROR:".mysql_error());
    while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        ?> 
            <option value="<?=$arr['sub_category_id']?>" <? if($_POST['Type'] == $arr['sub_category_id']) { ?> selected="selected" <? } ?> ><?=$arr['name']?></option>
        <?
    }

    ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Javascript function:

```
function relodme()
{
   document.forms[0].action="test1.php";  //your page name give here....
   document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you looking for is called a dependent select. It have barely nothing to do with php (except populating select options). I've found a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7YGb3/) for your case. You will need to install jquery to implement it in your code.

```
var $city = $(".city").on('change', function() {
  $city.not(this).get(0).selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about jQuery or CSS.

Look at this example (jQuery): http://dev7studios.com/dropit/

Answer (score 0):

so you have to use ajax to do this

```
$(document).on("change","first select box",function(){
    var id = $("first select box").val();
    $.ajax({
         url: "path to your file where you should write db code",
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "HTML",
         async: false,
         data: {"id": id},
         success: function(data) {
              $("second select box").html(data);  
           // here directly manipulate the data in controller or get the data in success function and manipulate .                   
      }
  });

})
```

in the file where you write db code

```
$a = "";
foreach(rows fro db as $a){
    $a .= "<select value='db id'><?= name ?></select>";
}
echo $a;
```

we are capturing $a to out normal file add making that as the value for our second select box.

Hope it hlps